# Slightly confused about what Artisan::callSilent does

Tags: laravel, laravel-artisan

I have a web route in my laravel project, and in that web route currently I'm calling an Artisan command I have defined in `app/Console/Commands`. I'm doing `Artisan::call(command)`.

So, it's my understanding first of all that when I call it like that, my web request will wait for that to complete before it continues into the next bit of code, is that right? Does it  wait for `Artisan::call` to complete?

I would like a solution that doesn't wait, and I have one potential workaround, but before I use my workaround, I want to make sure `Artisan::callSilent()` doesn't do what I want it to do. If I use `callSilent` instead, will that run the artisan command in the backround without blocking the rest of the web request process?

Comment: `Artisan::call` does not stop your requests, I have never used `callSilent` so I have no idea what it does. What issues did you encounter?

Comment: @matiaslauriti I can run some tests and find out for myself, I have been under the impression for a long time that `Artisan::call` is a request-blocking action, but I would be thrilled to find out I'm wrong. Thanks, I'll test.

Comment: `Artisan::call` is synchronous, I think you need a job that you can dispatch to the queue

Comment: I think you're right @krisgjika, I'm running tests and it's blocking the request processing like i thought

Comment: to clarify, it should only block the current request until it finishes (like calling a function), not other requests on the same endpoint

Comment: @TKoL sorry, I had in my mind that you were executing `php artisan command` instead of literally calling `Artisan::call` in your code, I do not know why I thought that. So yes, it is blocking because the outcome (output) depends on the command, so it must run in sync

Comment: `function call` has `return $this->runCommand($command, $arguments, $this->output);`, while `function callSilent` has `return $this->runCommand($command, $arguments, new NullOutput);`. So it looks like callSilent just doesn't send any output.

Comment: Thanks @aynber - feel free to post that as an answer. Please include the fact that callSilent is blocking still.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [CallsCommand.php](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/11.x/src/Illuminate/Console/Concerns/CallsCommands.php) shows the following functions:

```
   /**
     * Call another console command.
     *
     * @param  \Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command|string  $command
     * @param  array  $arguments
     * @return int
     */
    public function call($command, array $arguments = [])
    {
        return $this->runCommand($command, $arguments, $this->output);
    }

    /**
     * Call another console command without output.
     *
     * @param  \Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command|string  $command
     * @param  array  $arguments
     * @return int
     */
    public function callSilent($command, array $arguments = [])
    {
        return $this->runCommand($command, $arguments, new NullOutput);
    }
```

So as the comments say, `callSilent` does the same thing as the call command, but doesn't send any output. There's also a `callSilently()`, which just calls `callSilent`, so it's basically an alias.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so for the record

`Artisan::call()` is blocking, and `Artisan::callSilent()` ... well, it doesn't even exist on my installed version of laravel, on the server I'm working on, so I have no idea.

I'm using a workaround like this:

```
    $command = "php artisan " . $command ." > /dev/null 2>/dev/null &";
    shell_exec($command);
```